# Output window not displaying projects

Tags: visual-studio

I have roughly 6 solutions in my project, I use to be able to open the output window and choose a project from the menu and see any errors / exceptions thrown for selected project, however, since making the swap to VS 2022 my projects are no longer listed within the output dropdown when running the solution:

[image]

I can't figure out how I can make them appear, has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Kinda weird, I didn't work for that project, but when I opened another project it worked as expected.